# Not able to send invitation to facebook friends from my website?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-requests, facebook-invite

I am using the following code to send invitations to my facebook friends but it opens request pop up but no invitations are received to my friends:

```
<div>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
```

if (top.location != self.location) {
           top.location = self.location
            }

```
        FB.init({
            appId: 'my_app_id',
            cookie: true,
            status: true,
            xfbml: true
        });

        function FacebookInviteFriends() {
            FB.ui({
                method: 'apprequests',
                message: '9lessons Programming Blog Topics focused on Web Programming.'
            });
        }
    </script>
    <a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();">Facebook Invite Friends</a>
</div>
```

i am following the [This link to to do this.](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html#livedemo)

please help me. please help me find where i am doing wrong.
here is the screenshoot of my apps settings[image]

Comment: Do you have a canvas app set up on Facebook?

Comment: @CBroe i have added screenshot of the App

Comment: Take your app out of sandbox mode …

Answer (score 0):

I have did nothing just "Take my app out of sandbox mode" and upload the page on Live website. It is working fine there. i think facebook was not able to send invitations from localhost. So here is the code i have used to sent invitations from facebook.:

```
 <div id="fb-root">
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="FbRequest('If you want to fulfill your wishes then do not miss the opertuanty, huury up and join WishIsDone, A platform where you can fulfill your as well as your friends wishes...!','609416079110673');">
    Send Request</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FbRequest(message, data) {
        FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: message, data: data, title: 'Share this site with your friends' },
            function (response) {
                // response.request_ids holds an array of user ids that received the request
                var receiverIDs;
                if (response.request) {
                    var receiverIDs = response.to;  // receiverIDs is an array holding all user ids
                    alert(receiverIDs);
                }
            }
    );
    }
    // typical application initialization code for your site
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'app_Id',
            session: {},
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };
</script>
```

That's all and thanks to all who replied to my question.